# Error while copying: "no such file or directory"

Tags: copy

```
belkacem@belkacem:~$ sudo cp media/belkacem/01CF36CD84AC8C90/Originals/stvbios.zip /usr/share/games/mame/roms
cp: cannot stat 'media/belkacem/01CF36CD84AC8C90/Originals/stvbios.zip': No such file or directory
```

Why am I getting this message? What seems to be the problem?

[image]

Comment: The leading `/` is missing at `media/...`

Answer (score 3):

You need a `/` in front of `media`

```
sudo cp /media/belkacem/01CF36CD84AC8C90/Originals/stvbios.zip /usr/share/games/mame/roms
```

will work, assuming the path is correct

---

**Explanation of the error**

The mountpoint of your external device is in the directory `/media`. the first `/` specifies the root directory - all full *absolute* paths start with `/` You can use *relative* paths without `/` but this depends on *where you are*. For example, when you open a terminal you are in your home directory, so you can see the contents of your `Downloads` directory like this

```
ls Downloads
```

or move to your Documents and list the contents like this

```
cd Documents; ls
```

and so on...